# jqgrid getPage() getRow() null values on Oracle Application Server 10

Tags: ajax, jqgrid, oracle10g, servlets

My app is working allright in oc4j standalone (grids are working as they should) but when I deploy to OAS 10g Release 3 (10.1.3.1.0) any grid would not display any rows, yet I'm able to Insert a record if I want to.
I tried the log files from OAS both application and instance one; everything seems to work allright (there are no error logs just the hibernate sql trace.)

I wasn't able to post a pic of firebug console with all the right values:(...

Firebug tells me that the values for the grid are sent the way the supposed to
but apparently they are not getting to the server or something, because when the app its gonna use the values for page and rows they are somehow null

```
public void readGrid() {
    JQGridJSONModel json = new JQGridJSONModel();
    int page = Integer.valueOf(getPage());
    int block = Integer.valueOf(getRows());

    try {...
```

this is the error that I receive in the firebug HTML tab:

```
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: null at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:415) 
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:553) 
at com.taca.tariff.action.admin.security.SecUserCrudAction.readGrid(SecUserCrudAction.java:61) 
at com.taca.tariff.action.comun.ComunAction.fetchCrudMethod(ComunAction.java:174) 
at com.taca.tariff.action.admin.security.SecUserCrudAction.execute(SecUserCrudAction.java:114) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263) 
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164) a
t com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at com.taca.tariff.action.comun.ActiveSessionInterceptor.intercept(ActiveSessionInterceptor.java:50) 
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248) 
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52) 
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485) 
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77) 
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91) 
at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:15) 
at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129) 
at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77) 
at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17) 
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp.doFilter(ActionContextCleanUp.java:102) 
at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17) 
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) 
at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:619) 
at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:368) 
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.handleNotFound(HttpRequestHandler.java:1032) 
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:906) 
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:448) 
at com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:302) 
at com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:190) 
at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260) 
at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Since I'm not able to debug with the server its kind of what do I do next situation.
because they work alright in oc4j standalone, its like the request its not hitting  the server, surprisingly I can add a record if I want to.

Im using Struts2, Hibernate 3.5, spring 3.0.5, sitemesh.

I would really appreciate any clues about what might be happening?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update Situation solved :D
apparently the problem was that the server would not aloud GET METHOD only POST 
so I change the mtype to POST and  jqgrid its working alright now...